# Plot only one grob after gtable_filter

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gtable

I am trying to select or resize the plot margins for this figure that I have created after I have filtered the labels, I am left with this white part that I would like to get rid of as shown on the image. [image]

Thank you

Below my reproducible code:

```
df=structure(list(Estimate = c(0.1784, 0.073, 0.0619, 0.1367, 0.1795, 
0.087), name = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Intercept", 
"Doctor spouse", "8 years experience", "3 years experience", 
"1 year experience", "Female"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Intercept", "Male to", "0 Years Experience to", 
"No Spouse to"), class = "factor"), upper.95 = c(0.209, 0.0899, 
0.0858, 0.1606, 0.2034, 0.1077), lower.95 = c(0.1478, 0.0561, 
0.038, 0.1129, 0.1556, 0.0662), resp_type = c("Legislator", "Legislator", 
"Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                        -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)

p1=df %>%
  filter(name!="Intercept") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y= Estimate*100))+
  geom_point(shape = 1)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = "longdash")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = upper.95*100, ymin = lower.95*100), width = 0.001)+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(group ~.,scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = "bold", angle=0, vjust = 1))+
  xlab("")



gg=ggplotGrob(p1)
plot_filtered2 <- gtable_filter(gg, 
                     "(background|panel|strip_l|axis-b|ylab-l|guide-box|title)", trim=TRUE)


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(plot_filtered2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this from where you are (assuming you wish to keep all the elements you have selected from the `gtable` and for some reason don't want to get the same effect by simply using `element_blank` as Dan Adams suggests) is to set the widths of the first 6 columns of your `gtable` to 0 cm:

```r
plot_filtered2$widths[1:6] <- unit(rep(0, 6), "cm")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(plot_filtered2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get this effect simply by omitting the elements of the plot you want to drop in the `ggplot()` call itself by specifying `element_blank()` within the `theme()` for each.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Estimate = c(0.1784, 0.073, 0.0619, 0.1367, 0.1795, 0.087), name = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Intercept", "Doctor spouse", "8 years experience", "3 years experience", "1 year experience", "Female"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Intercept", "Male to", "0 Years Experience to", "No Spouse to"), class = "factor"), upper.95 = c(0.209, 0.0899, 0.0858, 0.1606, 0.2034, 0.1077), lower.95 = c(0.1478, 0.0561, 0.038, 0.1129, 0.1556, 0.0662), resp_type = c("Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator", "Legislator")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  filter(name != "Intercept") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = Estimate * 100)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = "longdash") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = upper.95 * 100, ymin = lower.95 * 100), width = 0.001) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(group ~ .,
             scales = "free",
             space = "free",
             switch = "y") +
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
        )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>